# Unittesting Ansible collections with Pytest

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, ansible, pytest, python-unittest

I am new to cloud/devops.

I have made an ansible collection that has two roles. The roles are about bringing a linux vm to a certain state. I have executed these roles against a target vm and it works well.

Next thing I need to do is conduct a sanity and unit test. How do I test the ansible connection with Sanity and Unittest (pytest).

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible's official documentation does offer some tips/samples on writing unit tests with pytest and mock data at

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/community/collection_contributors/collection_unit_tests.html#example-of-unit-tests

I was able to add test cases against some of the util methods I have in my collection using the given sample. If you have a sample code, I might be able to answer better.